# Python selenium generates stale element reference error when calling hover function

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I need help with my selenium project.
I'm trying to get the data from all the post of a given instagram profile by hovering each post at a time but when it reaches the last posts and calls the hover.perform function I get this error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

The error is generated because is unable to find the posts but I can't figure out why.

This is the link to my code: https://github.com/binksdev/pythonApps/blob/master/InstaScrapper/scrapper.py

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. The code is too much to debug your problem